# Java real time audio output monitoring

Tags: java, audio, real-time, fft, audio-recording

I want to monitor the sound output (anything that speakers plays) from java code. I've checked java sound API but I can't find a solution for such a simple task. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/1579071/Java-Sound-Getting-Started-Part-2-Capture-Using-Specified-Mixer.htm) but I always get: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: interface TargetDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 8000.0 Hz, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame`. Searched enough around but I didn't find anything.

The general purpose of my project is a simple sofware with a basic beat-detection from the sound. So, I need to sample the sound, apply FFT (visualize the result) and then some algorithms for beat detection there. Everything is a real time process. I don't know if there is any open source project or library out there in java that will the job for me.

Any help/ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks